# Is using treated wood safe for smoking meat?

Tags: meat, smoking

I have some broken hickory drum sticks that I was going to throw out; but could these be useful for smoking meat? I would assume the wood is treated.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea, but maybe your meat would have rhythm? Mambo chicken?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Good lord no. You have no idea how the drumsticks were treated or with what chemicals (cyanide derivatives are often used in pressure-treated woods, for example).

No. No no no no no.

Comment: +1: Also, treated wood tends to release a lot of PCBs when burned. Cancer city.

Comment: Cyanide and arsenic have mostly been phased out for pressure treated wood since about 2002, but they still use some pretty nasty chemicals in the stuff that you wouldn't want to ingest.